# loading the same page with and without session variables

Tags: asp.net

I have an aspx page. This page is used for both create and edit. 
While editing, I set a session variable and load the same page.
While creating , user has to click on menu option and it get redirected to "CreatePage.aspx".
While editing, it will be redirected on click of a column in a grid . this time the response.redirect happens to the same page with Session["Id"] set to some value. Now my question is how and when do I set the session to null?
This should work for Create and Edit using the same page. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The how is easy: 
`Session["Id"] = null`.

About the when: Can the user **cancel** a edit/creation? If so, what happens then?
The change of the session variable should be done when the user clicks on either the menu option or the grid column AND when the operation has finished (by either an **OK** or a **Cancel**).

Anyways, Changing data in a grid can easily be done with the GridView control. [You can see an example here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972948.aspx). So you might be trying to "reinvent the wheel" here...

Comment: Hi,thanks for your input. However I am not looking for an inline edit in the gridview. I need to redirect to another page. this page has controls which could be used for Create as well as edit. My only concern is how will i know whether I have to create or edit dependinig on Session value. So I need to know of a mechanism wherein I can clear that session value . also I need to know when can I clear the session. This session should persist during the postback when havinf session value intact.

Comment: @KusumShetty - Session variables do persist during postback, so that is not a problem. As I said above, there are 2 places where you should decide if you want to modify the variable in: 1. When you KNOW the user wants to either edit/create (this is easy, it's when he pressed the grid column or menu option) 2. When the operation has finished (he pressed cancel, he pressed ok). The only missing information that you didn't provide is what should happen if he pressed cancel for instance. Do you HAVE a cancel button?

Comment: So tell me when should I clear the session variable? Lets say user has been redirected to this page after setting a session variable and the page loads accordingly. Now user wants to create a new entity. so he goes to the menu and click on 'Create'. at this point in time, I have to ensure that the session is null. How do I achive this?

Comment: When the user clicks the menu option to create a new entity - In that function set the: Session["Id"] = null

Comment: Its not a function. It comes from Menu item click.The navigate url proprty is already set there.

Comment: Hi,Please find below the code to load the menu. It comes from database and will happen in master page code behind.